# Ruby Socket.pair: "An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used"

Tags: ruby

Just out of my own curiosity, I've been digging through various Ruby standard libraries. The 'socket' library has a method that creates a socket pair. When I try to create one I get the following error message:

```
Errno::EAFNOSUPPORT: An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used. - socketpair(2)
```

The code I used is directly from the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html#method-c-pair):

```
s1, s2 = Socket.pair(:UNIX, :DGRAM, 0)
s1.send "a", 0
s1.send "b", 0
p s2.recv(10) #=> "a"
p s2.recv(10) #=> "b"
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Note: I'm on a windows machine

Comment: Trying to use unix sockets on windows machine? Good luck with that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're on Windows, the problem is this line:

```
Socket.pair(:UNIX, :DGRAM, 0)  #=> :UNIT refers to UNIX stream socket
```

Try this instead:

```
Socket.pair(:INET, :STREAM, 0) # TCP socket
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Unfortunately, I'm getting a similar error: `Errno::EPROTOTYPE: A protocol was specified in the socket function call that does not support the semantics of the socket type requested. - socketpair(2)`

Comment: @effbott Could you try changing `:DGRAM` for `:STREAM`?

Comment: That worked! Thank you. If you edit your answer to include :STREAM instead of :DGRAM I'll accept it.